# Why do waves reflect in phase off of soft boundaries?

Tags: waves, reflection, boundary-conditions

Based on Newton's third law of motion I understand how waves reflect pi out of phase off of hard boundaries (see gif 1), but what would be the reasoning as to why waves reflect in phase off of **free boundaries**?(see gif 2),

I theorize that because the ring moves higher up than the amplitude of the free boundary (like shown in gif 2), the last particle of the string attached to the free boundary gains additional upward momentum (besides the upward momentum it already had due to the incident wave) and renders another disturbance in the string which that causes a reflected wave. But could someone please verify this theory (preferably with sources).

Gif1:

[image]

Gif2:

[image]

Comment: On the "free" boundary, how can an equal and oppositely directed force be applied to the wave that reaches the boundary?  Also, the simulation itself provides the answer you are seeking.

Comment: @DavidWhite As I'm not able to find horizontal vectors on the incident free boundary wave pulse, and here it's a positive wave pulse that only exerts an upward force, I guess an "equal an oppositely directed force" means a downward force. Unless it's the reaction force from moving the ring up (but that's very little with a free boundary) I have trouble finding this. Still, how would exerting a downward force on the wave render in phase reflection? As I mentioned in my question, I speculate that the free boundary going beyond the waves amplitude causes the reflection, would this be the answer?

Comment: On the fixed end, the only way for the rope to stay in place is if the fixture provides an equal and oppositely directed force to the rope when the wave reaches the boundary, per Newton's third law.  That force inverts the wave.  There can be no such force on the "free" end of the rope.

Comment: @David White Yes, I understand how a fixed end inverts a wave. But unlike a fixed end, I don't see the "free" end exerting a force on the wave, what makes it reflect then? The wave makes the free end move up and down, it also makes particles along the rope move up and down, why then does only the free end cause reflection? I intuit this might  have to do with the fact that the free end is the last part of the rope, moves beyond the waves amplitude or it's motion is limited to vertical motion, but don't know exactly how a "free" end can reflect the wave in phase.

Comment: The wave represents energy transmitted down the string.  That energy cannot just disappear.  When the wave gets to the free end, pieces of the string move up and down as the wave moves left to right, because it is a transverse wave.  When the ring gets to the top of its motion, it falls back down and causes an in-phase wave in the opposite direction, as seen in the simulation.  I don't understand why this is causing confusion.

Comment: @DavidWhite Right, I must be thinking about this the wrong way, but the reason I'm confused is because I don't see the "free end doing anything that "merits" a wave reflection, it simply moves up and down, particles in the wave also do that and no reflection comes out of that. I know there should be reflection, because energy can't disappear, but I don't understand how the motion of the free end provokes that, I guessed it had something to do with it's amplitude but I'm probably approaching this the wrong way. Thanks for your help David, maybe after taking a walk it will start to make sense.